# Get values in order from JSON object

Tags: arrays, json, object

I have an object like:

```
{'2014-01-01': 123, '2014-01-02': 456, '2014-01-03': 678}
```

I only need the values, while I loop through the object to fetch values, the order of the values has been changed, just randomly.

How can I get the values in order exactly like the original one? 
Thank you!

Comment: @griffonvulture jquery

Answer (score 1):

According to JSON specification, an object is an unordered set of name/value pairs, so it is impossible.